# isn't update in console in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

i am trying to update my firebase but is not appear what i updated 
this is my firebase data :

[image]

and then i exported my data :

[image]

then i updated and added another class :

[image]

and return a message is all updated :

[image]

but the problem is my data don't updated and stay in same data :

[image]

and this is my rules :

[image]

please help me to know what is and why i cant success to update that

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Firebase automatically creates keys for any values you write, and it automatically deletes keys that no longer have any values under them.

Since you specified no value for the `game` key, it is immediately deleted after you add it.

If you want to make sure the key gets written when you import the JSON, be sure to give it a value. E.g.

```
"game": true
```

But note that you don't need to pre-create keys like this, as Firebase will automatically create the `game` key when your app writes a value somewhere under it.